# How to close the jQuery context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, jquery-events

I'm displaying a contextmenu in jQuery, but am unable to close it.

These are the events that I am registering:

```js
function openContextMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#custom-menu")
        .css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    })
        .show(100);
    isContextMenuOpen = true;
}

function closeContextMenu(event) {
    console.log("Click called on document");
    if (isContextMenuOpen) {
        $("custom-menu").hide();
        console.log("Hide the context menu");
    }

    isContextMenuOpen = false;
}

function registerMenu() {

    $(document).on({
        contextmenu: function (event) {
            openContextMenu(event);
        },
        click: function (event) {
            closeContextMenu(event);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just have a typo:

`$("custom-menu")` in `closeContextMenu` should have a ID identifier:

```js
$("#custom-menu").hide();
```

Also, unless `isContextMenuOpen` is declared globally, it will remain scoped to `openContextMenu`, so the `hide` method will never execute.  You don't need it anyway as `hide` will work whether the element is visible or not.

Try this instead:

```js
function closeContextMenu(event) {
    $("#custom-menu").hide();
    console.log("Hide the context menu");
}
```

Also, just to plug my own answer, for some pretty sophisticated context menu handling, look at this:

#### [Use Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu as context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667336/1366033)

Comment: You are right there,I should instead be using an ID identifier.