# AngularJs Creating Context Menu With SubMenu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, contextmenu, dynamically-generated

I want to create a context menu in directive with angularjs, I can create a menu but can not create with submenu. I mean, open submenu on hover.

Sample Fiddle: [sample contextmenu](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2CB5/)

**My Controller:**

```
$scope.menuOptions = [
        ['New User', function () {
           console.log("New User");
        }],
        ['Delete', function () {
           console.log("Delete");
        }]
    ];
```

This fiddle is a very good,only I want to add submenu to this context menu. How can I create submenus based on this example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue you have here is, that you are using Bootstrap and Bootstrap doesn't support Submenus (anymore) out of the box. But [you can extend the functionality by adding some style sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024991/265165). The second issue is that you need to extend the `renderContextMenu` function to support nested arrays, currently it will only support simple arrays.

This is my attempt to solve your problem: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2CB5/82/)

Still a bit hacky but would work. This is what I changed:

- Changed the `menuOptions`, added a new example Item which doesn't have a function in second place but another array of items
- Extracted the functionality of the `angular.forEach...` method which is processing through the items to a new method `buildMenuItem` because i needed it for reuse to process the sub items
- Updated the routine with a `else if(item[1] instanceof Array)` check to detect a sub menu, this is where the sub menu is added, using recursion to add the sub menu items (you could basically have multiple levels, not just one)
- Added style sheets from the Link above to support sub menu styling

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question, [Bootstrap Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666601/use-bootstrap-3-dropdown-menu-as-context-menu) ,alternatively you can use this [AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect)