# Display a Popup

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Goal:
When you rightclick one of the row in the table, a popup with links should display, close to the row and cursor. A similiar concept is gmail's functionality.

Problem:
I cannot find a demo version in order to use it.

Information:
I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery..

[image]

Comment: use jquery context menu plugin which can give you support of right click http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

Comment: You should review the answer provided in this question, it contains a working demo too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666601/use-bootstrap-3-dropdown-menu-as-context-menu