# Find intersection of path when mouse move

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to find the intersection of path if mouse move over path.
I did google, but I want to achieve without any java script library.

It would be great if you can share example.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you could share what you've tried, or at least more details of what you have so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element