# How can I drag a div and keep the cursor on the same spot as I clicked it at?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to drag a div when I click on it but when I do it the div blinks and moves to the left, if I remove `offset` and put `position` instead it works but the cursor goes to the left top of the div.

```js
var selected = 0,
  x = 0,
  y = 0;

$.fn.isDraggable = function() {

  $(this).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    selected = $(this);
    $(selected).css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: e.pageX - $(selected).position().left,
      top: e.pageY - $(selected).position().top
    });
  });
  $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    if (selected !== 0) {
      selected = 0;
    }
  });
  $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    $(selected).css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: e.pageX - $(selected).offset().left,
      top: e.pageY - $(selected).offset().top
    });
  });

  return true;
};


$('#card').isDraggable();
```

```css
#card {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  top: calc(50% - 75px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>freeMarketRocks</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <div id="card">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why you didn't used jQueryUI draagable ? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @TCHdvlp I want to be able to do it Manually :)

Comment: let me check that in a jsfiddle...

Comment: http://liveweave.com/VOLc1m

Comment: There is an issue in your conception. You must rework event binding, let me see what can I do to help you...

Comment: You would need to offset for the mouses position within the element in order for it to not be in the corner

Comment: @Binvention That's exacly what I'm trying to accomplish but I don't know a command to get the cursor position relative to the div

Comment: You could calculate it using the elements position on the page wha the dimensions of the element itself

Comment: Try looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element

Comment: @Binvention I already did :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems here. First your event handler logic might result in a performance waste as you are asking your browser to constantly check for mouse movement, even if its not necessary.

Second, the calculation of the box coordiante is wrong, it must take the initial position in account. That's the purpose of my `deltaX` and `deltaY` variables in the fiddle

Here's a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/t2bapq5y/

Or Here:

```js
  var selected = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    boxX = 0,
    boxY = 0;

  $.fn.isDraggable = function() {

    $(this).on('mousedown', function(e) {
      selected = $(this);
      //get initial positions
      x = e.pageX;
      y = e.pageY;
      BoxX = $(selected).offset().left;
      BoxY = $(selected).offset().top;
      //bind mousemove
      $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
        //compute new coordinate
        deltaX = e.pageX - x;
        deltaY = e.pageY - y;
        $(selected).css({
          position: 'absolute',
          left: (BoxX + deltaX),
          top: (BoxY + deltaY)
        });
      });
    });
    //unbind when finished
    $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
      if (selected !== 0) {
        $(document).unbind("mousemove");
        selected = 0;
      }
    });

    return true;
  };


  $('#card').isDraggable();
```

```css
#card {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 10x;
  left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div id="card">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var selected = 0,
  x = 0,
  y = 0;

    $.fn.isDraggable = function() {

     var moveFrame, comStartX, comStartY, startMousePosX, startMousePosY;
 $(this).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  selected = $(this);
  moveFrame = true;
  comStartX = $(this).position().left;
  comStartY = $(this).position().top;
  startMousePosX = e.pageX;
  startMousePosY = e.pageY;
 });
        $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
  moveFrame = false;
        });
  

   $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (moveFrame){
      currPosX = comStartX + (e.pageX - startMousePosX);
      currPosY = comStartY + (e.pageY - startMousePosY);
      $(selected).css({position: 'absolute', 'left': currPosX + 'px', 'top': currPosY + 'px'});
     }
      });

  return true;
    };


$('#card').isDraggable();
```

```css
#card {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  top: calc(50% - 75px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>freeMarketRocks</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <div id="card">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```