# Drawing a straight line using mouse events inside a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

**This code is work proper in canvas but I want to do this inside a div tag not in canvas.**

```js
var canvasWidth = 180;
var canvasHeight = 160;
var canvas = null;
var bounds = null;
var ctx = null;
var hasLoaded = false;

var startX = 0;
var startY = 0;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var isDrawing = false;
var existingLines = [];

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#333333";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.beginPath();

  for (var i = 0; i < existingLines.length; ++i) {
    var line = existingLines[i];
    ctx.moveTo(line.startX, line.startY);
    ctx.lineTo(line.endX, line.endY);
  }

  ctx.stroke();

  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "darkred";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function onmousedown(e) {
  if (hasLoaded && e.button === 0) {
    if (!isDrawing) {
      startX = e.clientX - bounds.left;
      startY = e.clientY - bounds.top;

      isDrawing = true;
    }

    draw();
  }
}

function onmouseup(e) {
  if (hasLoaded && e.button === 0) {
    if (isDrawing) {
      existingLines.push({
        startX: startX,
        startY: startY,
        endX: mouseX,
        endY: mouseY
      });

      isDrawing = false;
    }

    draw();
  }
}

function onmousemove(e) {
  if (hasLoaded) {
    mouseX = e.clientX - bounds.left;
    mouseY = e.clientY - bounds.top;

    if (isDrawing) {
      draw();
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = canvasWidth;
  canvas.height = canvasHeight;
  canvas.onmousedown = onmousedown;
  canvas.onmouseup = onmouseup;
  canvas.onmousemove = onmousemove;

  bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  hasLoaded = true;

  draw();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    canvas {
      position: absolute;
      margin: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      border: solid 1px white;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div id="drawBoard">
    <!--I want to draw here-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Above code is fine , But i want to draw line inside a div(direct on document page) not in canvas. I don't have any idea to do this. please help me to do this or refer me some article on this.

[image]
I dont have idea even how can i start. Please refer me some related answer.

Comment: Why you want to draw inside div instead of canvas ?

Comment: i have a project where i have to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me apologyze for my enlgish, i'll try my best to explain!

You may be interested on using "SVG" lines for this purpose https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg since you can draw lines easly.

To acomplish this, you will need and SVG container, here you can find some information about how it works -> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

Once you have the container, you need to create and move lines inside using javascript, to do so, you need the following code:

```
    //To create 1
     document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line'); 
    //To select 1 
     document.querySelector('#nameOfTheLine')
    //To change its position 
    line.setAttribute('x1',x1);
    line.setAttribute('y1',y1);
    line.setAttribute('x2',x2);
    line.setAttribute('y2',y2);
    //To change its stroke so you can see it: 
    line.setAttribute("stroke", "color")
```

i'll give you this example that i made, its not the best but i hope you will find it usefull!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
      #canvas{
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="border">
        <svg id="canvas" width="500" height="400">
        </svg>
      </div>

      <script>
        /*Store the "svg" item in a variable */
        const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
        //Class to store the position
        class Vector2D{
          constructor(x,y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
          }
        }

        //Variables that will store the initial and final position of the line before its drawn.
        let initialPosOfLine;
        let finalPosOfLine;
        //Variable to store the stage of the canvsa, if the user its drawing or not.
        let drawingOverCanvas = false;
        //Variable to store the current index of the line
        let lineIndex = 0;

        // Code that will be executed once the user click with the mouse in the svg.
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
          //If we are drawing, do nothing.
          if(drawingOverCanvas) return;
          /*Calculate position relative to div -- Done by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element */
          var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          var x = event.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
          var y = event.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.
          //Change the variable drawingOverCanvas to true since now we are drawing
          drawingOverCanvas = true;
          //Store the mouse position over the div as the initialPos;
          initialPosOfLine = new Vector2D(x , y);
          //draw a line at the starting point;
          drawToPos(initialPosOfLine, initialPosOfLine, 'line'+lineIndex , false);
        });
        // Code that will be executed once the user click with the mouse in the svg.
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
          //If we are not drawing, do nothing.
          if(!drawingOverCanvas) return;
          //Set the varible to "false" as we are not drawing now.
          drawingOverCanvas = false;
            /*Calculate position relative to div -- Done by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element */
          var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          var x = event.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
          var y = event.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.

          //Store the final position as a vector.
          finalPosOfLine = new Vector2D(x, y);

          //Set the line to its correct position
          drawToPos(initialPosOfLine, finalPosOfLine, 'line'+lineIndex , true);
          //Increse the index of the line for the next one.
          lineIndex++;
        });

        //Draw the line when the user move the mouse
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
          //if we are not drawing, do nothing.
          if(!drawingOverCanvas) return;
            /*Calculate position relative to div -- Done by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element */
          var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          var x = event.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
          var y = event.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.

          //Store the mouse position as the "final" position
          finalPosOfLine = new Vector2D(x, y);
          //Draw a line from the initialPos to the current Mouse pos.
          drawToPos(initialPosOfLine, finalPosOfLine, 'line'+lineIndex , true);
        });

        //Draw a line between 2 points, if move its true, it will move the line instead of making it
        function drawToPos(initial, final, id, move){
          //Declare a new Line in SVG
          var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');

          //If we are moving and existent line, set "line" to the current line, else, give to the new line the id attribute.
          if(move){ line = document.querySelector('#'+id) } else { line.setAttribute('id',id) };
          // If we are creating a new line, define its initial position
          if(!move) line.setAttribute('x1',initial.x);
          if(!move) line.setAttribute('y1',initial.y);
          //Define its final position
          line.setAttribute('x2',final.x);
          line.setAttribute('y2',final.y);
          //Define its stroke.
          line.setAttribute("stroke", "black")
          //Apend the line to the SVG canvas
          canvas.append(line);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const container = document.createElement('DIV');

function drawLine(){
  for(o=0;o<59;o++){
 container.innerHTML+='<span id="o'+o+'" style="position:absolute;">&bull;</span>'; 
}
  
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  for(o=0;o<59;o++){
    eval('o'+o).style.left=o+"px";
    eval('o'+o).style.top=o+"px";
  }
}drawLine();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!