# Hey! I'm trying to make a crosshair follow my mouse, but e.mouseX and e.mouseY don't work accurately

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code:

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctxt = canv.getContext('2d');
const w = canv.width;
const h = canv.height;
canv.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  ctxt.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawLine(e.clientX, 0, e.clientX, h);
  drawLine(0, e.clientY, w, e.clientY);
})
function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  ctxt.beginPath();
  ctxt.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctxt.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctxt.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

e.clientX and e.clientY aren't working accurately (run code).
How do I fix this?

Comment: You can't resize a Canvas with CSS. You can, however, set `canv.width` and `canv.height` in the JavaScript code, like so: `canv.width = 1000;`

Comment: Or resize with CSS but then remember to make sure to properly scale your x/y dimensions by looking at the canvas's `getBoundingClientRect`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real mouse position in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not use CSS to set the size of the canvas, you should instead use the attributes `width` and `height`.

Secondly, you should use the relative mouse position (relative to the canvas) so that crosshair is accurate. For that we will use code from this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111623/9867451).

Here is how it should be done:

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctxt = canv.getContext('2d');
const w = canv.width;
const h = canv.height;

const rect = canv.getBoundingClientRect();

canv.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {

  const x = e.pageX - rect.left;
  const y = e.pageY - rect.top;

  ctxt.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctxt.beginPath();
  ctxt.moveTo(0, y);
  ctxt.lineTo(w, y);
  ctxt.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctxt.lineTo(x, h);
  ctxt.stroke();
});

/* drawLine is really not necessary */
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* no sizing here */
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

**Note:** Use `pageX` and `pageY` instead of `clientX` and `clientY` so that if scrolling is involved you'll still get accurate tracking. `clientX` and `clientY` don't take scrolling into account whereas `pageX` and `pageY` do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale the mouse position to the real drawing size of the canvas. The css style do not set the size of the drawing area only the size of the html element.

```js
const canv = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctxt = canv.getContext("2d");

const rect = canv.getBoundingClientRect();

canv.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {

  ctxt.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  const ex = (e.pageX - rect.left) / canv.offsetWidth * canv.width;
  const ey = (e.pageY - rect.top) / canv.offsetHeight * canv.height;

  drawLine(ex, 0, ex, canv.height);
  drawLine(0, ey, canv.width, ey);

});

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  ctxt.beginPath();
  ctxt.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctxt.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctxt.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Without the [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height) and [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) html attribute default values of `width=150` and `height=300` will be applied.