# How to get mouse position regardless of screen size javasript

Tags: javascript, html, web, coordinates, screen

I need to get the current mouse position relative to a div.

i've tried using:

```
myDiv.onclick = () => {
  console.log(event.clientX) //X pos
}
```

and

```
myDiv.onclick = () => {
  console.log(event.screenX) //X pos
}
```

But they all return difference values depending on the screen size or browser window size, so how can i get the click position inside the div regardless of screen ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find mouse position relative to element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111623/13762301)

Comment: Yes just what i needed thanks!