# scrollable DIV with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I have a block with a scrollable `div` tag inside it on the left side: https://paste.pics/2b27787ffd9e5671df4d34b0b656ba2a

I want to scroll the `div` tag on the left side of the attached image when the mouse hovers on the right side of the attached image (brown background),
how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

without js you can able to scroll with fix height of div and css overflow property

Answer (score 0):

check [Find mouse position relative to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element) to catch cursor position on your right panel

using right panel size you'll easily compute position in % if need

compute the visible box of your left panel from cursor center position and change properties scrollTop and scrollLeft of your left panel accordingly

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop