# Return Exact Same Image Coordinates in JavaScript After Screen Resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, coordinates, react-bootstrap

I want to retrieve the exact coordinates on a png of a football field. I'm able to get some coordinates using `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop`, but unfortunately these begin to vary once the image is resized, or the page is opened on a different resolution or device.

[Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-nightingale-6j9cq?file=/src/App.js)

I need the coordinates to be exactly the same regardless of screen resolution or device, because I want to print to the user the exact yard on the pitch that the user has clicked on. Is there a way to do this in JavaScript? I had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element) but some of it was a bit confusing and I wasn't able to get what I wanted.

This is my React code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

import footballField from "./resources/images/AmFBfield.png";

function App() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);
  const printCoordinates = (e) => {
    const x = e.pageX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    const y = e.pageY - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

    setX(x);
    setY(y);
  };

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col sm={4}>
        {x}:{y}
      </Col>
      <Col sm={8}>
        <Container>
          <img
            id="football-field"
            src={footballField}
            alt="football-field"
            style={{ width: "80%", height: "80%" }}
            onClick={(e) => printCoordinates(e)}
          />
        </Container>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want consistent click location within the image bounds without concern for the content of the image you can simply convert the `x` and `y` offset of the click relative to the image frame to percentages based on the height and width of the image as displayed.

Here using [`MouseEvent.offsetX/Y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) to return the offset of the click relative to the image element directly (you can access this via the `nativeEvent` property of React's synthetic event),and [`element.getBoundingRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to retrieve the height and width of the element.

```
const printCoordinates = (e) => {
  const { width, height } = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const { offsetX, offsetY } = e.nativeEvent

  setX(Math.round((offsetX / width) * 100));
  setY(Math.round((offsetY / height) * 100));
};
```

If, however, you want coordinates relative to the content of the image (ie. the actual yard line clicked) there are two options.

The simplest would be to create your 'pitch' image out of multiple parts, separating the borders, end zones and yardage into individual images and using the above method for each component.

Alternatively, to work with the single image that you have, you'll need to account for the border and end zones by subtracting them (as percentages of the total image height/width) from the percentage offset of the click and then mapping these corrected click offsets to the percentage of the total image that the actual pitch takes up in the image.

Here's a rough example from cursory percentage mapping of your image in which the border+endzone is 10% of the image width, and the top-border is 5% of the image height.

```
const printCoordinates = (e) => {
  const { width, height } = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const { offsetX, offsetY } = e.nativeEvent;

  // calculate percentage, subtract border/endzone percentage(10), map 80% to 100%, calculate yardage
  setX(Math.round(((((offsetX / width) * 100) - 10) / 80) * 100));
  // calculate percentage, subtract top-border percentage(5), map 90% to 100%, calculate yardage (53.3 yards total width)
  setY(Math.round(((((offsetY / height) * 100) - 5) / 90) * 53.3));
};
```

see: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/football-field-click-r4m9q)

Comment: Thanks @pilchard. What would be a way to split the pitch into multiple components, as mentioned in your first suggestion? I'm guessing I'll have to figure out a way to break the image into various `div`s, if I understand correctly.