# How to make a placementment tool for a model?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I followed tutorial from this [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dynamic-model-placement) and want to create a tool like TransformationExtension.

I found that the model I selected was not immediately centered on the cursor and there was a gap when dragging it. [image]

```
document.onmousemove = (event) => {
    if (!event.ctrlKey) return;

    let res = this.viewer.impl.hitTest(
        event.clientX,
        event.clientY,
        true,
        null,
        [this.viewer.model.getModelId()]
    );
    let pt = null;

    if (res) {
        pt = res.intersectPoint;
    } else {
        pt = viewer.impl.intersectGround(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    }

    let tr = this.selectedModel.getPlacementTransform();
    tr.elements[12] = pt.x;
    tr.elements[13] = pt.y;
    tr.elements[14] = pt.z;
    this.selectedModel.setPlacementTransform(tr);
    this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);
};
```

Comment: Maybe you need to subtract the canvas offset from `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` with something like this : `function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: e.clientX - rect.left,
    y: e.clientY - rect.top
  };
} ` ?

Comment: Yes.. Its works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexAR mentioned, when finding the cursor position relative to a specific DOM element using the `clientX` and `clientY` values, you have to remember subtracting the element's client bounding rect: [Find mouse position relative to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element).

Btw. I've recently built another sample Forge app that can be used to drag&drop new models into the viewer that you might find helpful: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-assembly-configurator. The main drag&drop logic is implemented in the [setupDragDrop](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-assembly-configurator/blob/master/server/public/scripts/project.js#L105-L195) function.