# How to get mouse X position of a mouse event of a div (and not of its children) with React 17?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent, mousemove

I have a simple snippet where I attach a `onMouseMove` listener to a given div:

```
<div onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
</div>
```

I want to know the X position of the mouse pointer within the parent div where I attached the mouse listener to. However, the event seems to only contain references to the children divs (as `target`), and the root (as `currentTarget`).

The event's `nativeEvent` property also is not helping it seems.

I'm on React 17. I think this is making it harder as previously the `currentTarget` would point to that div where I placed the listener to, but on React 17 these listeners to the root.

How can I get the coordinates within the div I attached the listener to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works as expected in `react` version `17.0.2`

```
function Component() {
  const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    let rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    let y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    console.log(x, y);
  };
  return (
    <div onMouseMove={onMouseMove}>
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111623/14207720) answer and a comment on it, about using a `currentTarget`

Comment: Ah, nice trick with the bounding rectangle. Thanks!