# Find position of cursor in monaco editor from window object

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-extension, monaco-editor

I am trying to find the cursor position in an editor instance of a monaco editor on the page that has already been created. I am doing this through a browser extension so I don't have access to the code that created the editor.

I just want to find the position of the cursor in the editor. But for that I need to somehow get the instance of the editor on the page.

Can I somehow do this using a combination of the model and the DOM element of the editor?

I can see there is a `monaco.editor` property on `window` but `window.monaco.editor.getEditors()` is not a function.

```
const model = monaco.editor.getModels()[0]; // Returns the actual model used on the page

const container = document.querySelector(".monaco-editor").parentElement; // the editor in the DOM

const editorInstance = window.monaco.editor.getEditors(); // Not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a reference to the editor container element, you could just do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element) to get the mouse position relative to the top-left of the editor (or am I not understanding your requirements?)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. However, I'm specifically looking for the cursor position in the monaco editor's lines and columns. So what I need out of it in the end is a startColumn number and a startLineNumber so I can apply edits to the editor at that position. These are tracked by the monaco library, and I'm not sure they are related to the mouse position since you can have your mouse somewhere other than the cursor position. There is a `getPosition()` method on an editor instance of a monaco editor that would give me exactly that. But first I need the editor instance itself.

Comment: Whoops, I somehow missed you wanted the *cursor* position, not the *mouse* position. Sorry for the noise!

Comment: Also, Monaco is one of the few HTML code editor libraries that provide multi-cursor functionality, so your code will have to deal with that.