# how to create a repositionable image

Tags: javascript, ajax, image

i would to create an image that the user can drag and drop any where in the page.

then the position would be saved so when he opens the page again it will be where he left it.

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849030/how-do-i-get-the-coordinate-position-after-using-jquery-drag-and-drop ???

Comment: The easiest way to go is http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you want to record the mouse position, then absolutely position the element based on where the mouse is, and on mouse up serialise the coordinates and save them. You could either send them to the server via ajax, or (depending on context), save them into the users local storage. That would have the benefit of avoiding a server round trip if the use case is fairly trivial.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable is a nice example of how this would work without having to do the difficult parts!