# How to access the co-ordinates of an element as it's being dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jquery-ui-draggable

If I am using this function to make an element draggable using jQuery ui draggable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#draggableSquare").draggable();
});
```

How can I access the co-ordinates of the element as it's moved around?

Comment: it seems the aswer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849030/how-do-i-get-the-coordinate-position-after-using-jquery-drag-and-drop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the coordinate position after using jQuery drag and drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849030/how-do-i-get-the-coordinate-position-after-using-jquery-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    drag: function(event,ui) {
        //relative to container: ui.position.left and ui.position.top 
        //ralative to page: ui.offset.left and ui.offset.top
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwFqd/2/)