# How to make jQuery UI Draggable/Droppable work properly in this case

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have a floating toolbar with tools buttons in it. The toolbar itself is draggable using its header with title "Basic tools". Below the toolbar there is a workspace filling the whole page. Buttons on the toolbar are draggable too and droppable to the workspace. When I drag/drop a button to the workspace, it turns into a rectangle widget with some content in it.

My issue is that I want an icon to be dropped only when it's over the gridded workspace, not over the toolbar. I have added console.log to track Draggable/Droppable events and it seems that the workspace emits `drop` event event if I drop the element on the toolbar. I suppose it's because the workspace is below the toolbar. So, when it's being dropped on the toolbar, it should revert back to its initial position in the toolbar.

[image: Toolbar with tools]

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine where the tool is dropped: [How do I get the coordinate position after using jQuery drag and drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849030/how-do-i-get-the-coordinate-position-after-using-jquery-drag-and-drop)
You also have to determine where your toolbox is placed: http://api.jquery.com/position/
Then you have to determine the width and height of your toolbox: http://api.jquery.com/width/

After that calculate the rectangle of your toolbox and check if the tool is placed there. If it is placed there then deny dropping, if not allow dropping.