# returning the same x and y co-ordinates on two differently sized mobile devices

Tags: javascript, .net, mobile

I'm using .net 4.5. There is a fair bit of info on x and y co-ordinates in javascript eg:

[How do I get the coordinate position after using jQuery drag and drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849030/how-do-i-get-the-coordinate-position-after-using-jquery-drag-and-drop)

I've got a fairly simple web app that is targeted at mobile devices where there's some drag and drop functionality and the x and y coordinates are stored.
Basically there will be a background image of a room and you drag and drop a piece of furniture in the room on one mobile device (User 1), the x and y co-ords get stored on a server and that piece of furniture will appear on another mobile device (User 2) ideally in the same position irrespective of screen size.

I thought the best way to handle it so it doesn't get too complicated was just to set the width and height of a div container say to 320 x 400 and restrict drag and drop to that container. And then whether the screen size is 600 x 800, 500 x 700, etc. on another persons device it shouldn't matter and the x and y co-ordinates will always be the same relative to the 320 x 400 div container. But alas, I can't get that working.

Any tips would be sensational.

```
css
    .imgContainer {
        height: 400px;
        width: 320px;
    }

    img {
        position: relative;
    }


View
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/image.jpg" class="img-responsive" />

        <img src="~/Content/Images/chair.png"  />
    </div>
```

Comment: You have to keep in mind the offset your div could have. Coordinates are always calculated as document coordinates. Second answer to the question you mention is a good example. You have to substract the offset of your drop zone from the coordinates reported to your code.

Comment: Thanks. But if i create a div or canvas say 320 x 400  won't the upper left corner have coordinates (0,0)?

Comment: If there is no CSS and no other content your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   // Mouse co-ordinate position will get using onStart Fn.

    function onStart(evt, ui){
        ui.position.top=Math.round(ui.position.top);
        ui.position.left=Math.round(ui.position.left);
    }

   // After dropping will get using Dragged object positions from onDrop Fn.

    function onDrop(evt, ui){
        left = ui.draggable.css('left');
        top = ui.draggable.css('top');
    console.log(left, top);

    }

   // You can Restrict the container using containment parent.. 

    $( ".selector" ).draggable({
      containment: "parent"
    });
```